# SQL ... trouble with insert into statements

Tags: sql, mysql

```sql
CREATE TABLE easy_drinks(drink_name VARCHAR(20), main VARCHAR(10),amount1 DEC(3,1),second VARCHAR(25), amount2 DEC(3,2),directions VARCHAR(255)); 
INSERT INTO easy_drinks
(drink_name,main,amount1,second, amount2,directions) 
VALUES
(‘Black thorn’,’tonicwater’,1.5 ,’pineapple_juice’,1 ,’stir with ice,strain into cocktail glass with lemon twist’), 
(‘BlueMoon’,’soda’,1.5,’blueberry_juice’,0.75, ‘strain into cocktail glass with lemon twist),
 (Ohmygosh’,’peach_nectar’,1,’pineapple_juice’,1,’stir with ice’,’strain into shot glass’),
 (‘Lime_fizz’,’sprite’,1.5,’lime_juice’,0.75,’stir with ice,strain into a cocktail glass), 
(‘kiss on lips’,’cherry juice’,2,’apricot nector’,7,’serve over ice with straw’), 
(‘hot gold’,’peach nectar’,3,’orange juice’,6,’pour hot orange juice in mug and peach nectar’), (‘lone tree,’soda’,1.5,’cherry juice’,0.75,’stir with ice,strain into cocktail glass), (‘greyhound’,’soda’,1.5,’grapefruit juice’,5,’serve with ice,stir well’), (‘indian summer’,’apple juice’,2,’hot tea’,6,’add juice to mug and topoff with hot tea’), (‘bullfrog’,’iced tea’,1.5,’lemonade’,5,’serve over ice with lime slice’), (‘soda and it’,’soda’,2,’grape juice’,1,’shake in cocktail glass,no ice’);
```

this is the im using to create a table and add that data into it but it is showing me this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'thorn’,’tonicwater’,1.5 ,’pineapple_juice’,1 ,’stir with
> ice,strain ' at line 4

this is getting created i have problem with insert into can someone tell me what the problem is

i tried changing the datatypes still no use i want to create a table with all that data.

Comment: Perhaps a opy-and-paste issue, but use straight, single quotes for string literals. E.g `'hot gold'`-

Answer (score -2):

I run into a similar error sometimes. For some reason unbeknownst to me, SQL interprets the ' that you input as an apostrophe that is not "straight", and it requires a straight apostrophe. Try pasting the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE easy_drinks (
    drink_name VARCHAR(20),
    main VARCHAR(10),
    amount1 DEC(3,1),
    second VARCHAR(25),
    amount2 DEC(3,2),
    directions VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO easy_drinks (drink_name, main, amount1, second, amount2, directions) VALUES
('Black thorn', 'tonicwater', 1.5, 'pineapple_juice', 1, 'stir with ice, strain into cocktail glass with lemon twist'),
('BlueMoon', 'soda', 1.5, 'blueberry_juice', 0.75, 'strain into cocktail glass with lemon twist'),
('Ohmygosh', 'peach_nectar', 1, 'pineapple_juice', 1, 'stir with ice, strain into shot glass'),
('Lime_fizz', 'sprite', 1.5, 'lime_juice', 0.75, 'stir with ice, strain into a cocktail glass'),
('kiss on lips', 'cherry juice', 2, 'apricot nector', 7, 'serve over ice with straw'),
('hot gold', 'peach nectar', 3, 'orange juice', 6, 'pour hot orange juice in mug and peach nectar'),
('lone tree', 'soda', 1.5, 'cherry juice', 0.75, 'stir with ice, strain into cocktail glass'),
('greyhound', 'soda', 1.5, 'grapefruit juice', 5, 'serve with ice, stir well'),
('indian summer', 'apple juice', 2, 'hot tea', 6, 'add juice to mug and top off with hot tea'),
('bullfrog', 'iced tea', 1.5, 'lemonade', 5, 'serve over ice with lime slice'),
('soda and it', 'soda', 2, 'grape juice', 1, 'shake in cocktail glass, no ice');
```

Comment: it's the difference between [` the grave accent](https://www.ascii-code.com/96) and [‘ left single quotation mark](https://www.ascii-code.com/CP1252/145) or [’ right single quotation mark](https://www.ascii-code.com/CP1252/146)

Comment: Thx everyone for the help